# Using Sample data for User Onboarding

Tags: usability-testing, onboarding

I am currently working on the onboarding of a recruitment application. Modules in this application are inter dependent. If want to create a job opening, I have to create a Candidate first.

In the onboarding process, if the user goes and clicks the job opening instead of Candidate, I thought of asking the user if he is okay to add sample data here.

I have attached screenshots of my idea. Is it correct to give sample details to the user? is it good UX?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea, but I question why you have to create a candidate in order to create a job listing.  If you are recruiting, usually the listing will need to exist before you have candidates for it?  This flow seems strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

If the user clicks on job opening instead of Candidate, then you should **let him/her fill up the job opening form, without interruptions** (in this case, candidate creation is a big blocker).

- Firstly, you could ask the user: *If you want to create Job opening directly before creating a candidate?*
- If he proceeds, instead of asking for the user to give sample data, my suggestion is (also better from a usability perspective), **Log him in as a guest user** (such as *Guest19982* or *JobProvider221*). **Then you can ask him/her to fill up the candidate details later once they have completed their initial objective.**